# How do I delete other available networks from network scan list?

Tags: macos, network, wifi

My Macbook Pro (v10.6.8) is constantly automatically connecting to a neighbor's wifi - event though I've never connected to that network, and I have my own Wifi connection prioritized.  The system is constantly scanning for Other Networks and lists all of my neighbors' network ahead of mine.  I frequently need to reset the connection.  How do I remove the list of available networks, OR disable the system from scanning the neighborhood, OR lock the Wifi connection to my in-home network? Thanks!

Comment: I'm going to put a hold in this. The answer is "it depends" so we would need you to edit in your specific SSID names to be able to help you out. If someone else has a similar question - be sure to upload a screen shot of the saved networks they have in system preferences and list the names of both the desired network and the undesired network.

Answer (score 1):

You could check your "Preferred Networks" and make sure your WiFi Access point is listed first.

To do this Open the System Preferences and select "Network" then Select the WiFi network and click the Advanced button:

[image]

With the WiFi tab selected from the Advanced sheet you should see a list of your preferred networks, Add, Remove, Reorder as you see fit.

Comment: The problem sounds like it's the "Ask to join new networks" setting.

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to remove networks anywhere in the Network Preferences sheet.  How is one to utilize this fix without a way to delete the networks?  Not even the delete key on the keyboard is effective.

Answer (score 0):

If that network is not secured, it would try connecting to that automatically just because it is not secure. Try removing all networks that do not require a password to join, and that should fix it.

Using sdmeyers method is the correct way to removing networks from your preferences